# Keep cell format when referring to a date cell in an Excel formula

Tags: sql, excel, formula

I'm trying to generate SQL queries based on data from an Excel sheet.

So I did write this formula

```
="INSERT INTO "&$B$1&" VALUES('"&Personnel!A1&"','"&Personnel!B1&"','"&Personnel!C1&"','"&Personnel!D1&"','"&Personnel!E1&"','"&Personnel!F1&"','"&Personnel!G1&"','"&Personnel!H1&"','"&Personnel!I1&"','"&Personnel!J1&"','"&Personnel!K1&"','"&Personnel!L1&"','"&Personnel!N1&"','"&Personnel!O1&"','"&Personnel!Q1&"','"&Personnel!R1&"','"&Personnel!S1&"')"
```

Which almost works except the fact that datas from Date Cells on my "Personnel" sheet gives me things like `24136` when I'm expecting `29-01-1966`. How can i fix this and keep the original format ?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query to change those values to their text equivalent using the [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function e.g.

```
="INSERT INTO "&$B$1&" VALUES('"&TEXT(Personnel!A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"
```

Comment: `="INSERT INTO "&$B$1&" VALUES('"&Personnel!A1&"','"&Personnel!B1&"','"&Personnel!C1&"','"&Personnel!D1&"','"&Personnel!E1&"','"&Personnel!F1&"','"&Personnel!G1&"','"&Personnel!H1&"','"&TEXT(Personnel!I1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"','"&Personnel!J1&"','"&Personnel!K1&"','"&Personnel!L1&"','"&Personnel!N1&"','"&Personnel!O1&"','"&Personnel!Q1&"','"&Personnel!R1&"','"&Personnel!S1&"')"`

It gives me an error in my Formula :/.

Comment: The same error than on this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouBJD.png

Comment: @Ishiru I've just typed that text (without the newline in the middle) into a spreadsheet and it works fine for me